# How i can create extra route in resource Controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, routes

I have a resource Route in laravel by the name of PropertyController, But now I want to add create an extra function in this resource Controller.
. Please let me know how I can create a new route in this. because I am getting this error (Route [amenities.create] not defined.)

This is my resourece route

`Route::resource('property', 'PropertyController');`

And I create new Route in this

`Route::get('property/amenities', 'PropertyController@amenities'); (This route is showing route not define`

My View Link is this:

`<li>
                        <a href="{{ route('amenities.create') }}">
                            Add Amenities
                        </a>
                    </li>`

Comment: use ```route('property.create')```

Comment: This is a resource route, and it's working fine. But I want to add an extra route with this name route('amenities.create') in PropertyController.php

Comment: I guess you need to add after defining `get(...)->name('amenities.create');`. Because route function will look for route name existence. In your error message exactly says about this.

Comment: it's working fine, Thank You So much....Now I can Try to Insert data in my database

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that the new route is at the top of the resource route.

```
Route::get('property/amenities', 'PropertyController@amenities')->name('amenities.create'); 
Route::resource('property', 'PropertyController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Route::get('property/amenities', 'PropertyController@amenities')->name('amenities.create');
```

Hope it work.

Comment: Make sure this route is defined above the Route::resource()  definition, otherwise it will be overwritten by the PropertyController@show (`property/{id}`) action.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<li>
<a href="{{ url('property/amenities') }}"> Add Amenities</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? How does this create a new route?